# How to execute an remote .sql in mysql command line

Tags: mysql

I have a file located at `E:\Backup\sql\mybackup.sql`

I'm logging into command line and I'm at the command prompt `mysql>`

How would I restore the database mydatabase?

I thought it was

```
mydatabase > "E:\Backup\sql\mybackup.sql"
```

but it keeps saying

> unknown command at each `\`

Answer (score 8):

Run it like:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p mydatabase < "E:/Backup/sql/mybackup.sql"
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the escaping issue, you have your redirection operator the wrong way around. Assuming you are using a shell which supports redirection of STDIN, you could try:

```
mysql mydatabase < E:\\Backup\\sql\\mybackup.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

`\` is the delimiter. Put `\\` so you escape the `\`.

> For windows users, use forward slashes for the path delimiters. You
>   also don't need to enclose the path to the file in quotes. E.g., the
>   following works:
>
> mysql> source C:/Documents and Settings/My name here/My
>   Documents/spike_loadingMySQLDB/createTables.sql;

As stated in the comment in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

Comment: Do you need the quotes? Might give a try removing these :)

Answer (score 0):

The command is

```
source "E:/Backup/sql/mybackup.sql"
```

First, specify the database (`use dbname`) - if it's not specified in the backup file